# Autoloader Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend

Estou iniciando (estudando) projeto com zf onde ainda não estou utilizando módulos.

Tenho inicialmente o seguinte arquivo .../projetozend/application/models/Dbtable/Actor.php

```
<?php
class Application_Model_Actor extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'actor'; // Nome da tabela
    protected $_id = 'actor_id'; // campo id da tabela
}
```

Tenho também o controller index onde tem aactionIndex e estou tentando instanciar essa model de cima.

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $actor = new Application_Model_Actor();
}
```

Ai beleza porém estou com o seguinte problema: **Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_Actor' not found [...]**

Estou vendo que preciso configurar o *autoloader* do projeto na qual eu já dei uma pesquisada na web, mas não conseguir entender e implementar. A final qual é a maneira mais correta de fazer essa configuração?

Bem estou usando o ZF1 pois estou no estágio e aqui é usando essa versão.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal seria que o nome da classe fosse:

```
class Application_Models_Dbtable_Actor extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{...
```

Assim seguiria o padrão PSR-0, pois o *autoload* segue esse padrão.